# Save.npy masked array to a .npy array with NaNs where mask == True

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to convert a masked 3D numpy array to a numpy array with NaNs in place of the mask?  This way I can easily write the numpy array out using `np.save`.  The alternative is to find a way to write out the masked array with some clear indicator for elements that are masked.  I have tried:

```
a = np.ma.zeros((500, 500))
a.dump('test')
```

but I need the file to be in a format so it can be read into R.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A scan of [the masked array operations page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html#to-a-ndarray) shows `np.ma.filled` does what you are looking for. For example,

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4).astype(float)
mask = arr % 5 == 0

marr = np.ma.array(arr, mask=mask)
print(np.ma.filled(marr, np.nan))
```

yields

```
[[[ nan   1.   2.   3.]
  [  4.  nan   6.   7.]
  [  8.   9.  nan  11.]]

 [[ 12.  13.  14.  nan]
  [ 16.  17.  18.  19.]
  [ nan  21.  22.  23.]]]
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the masked array's [`filled`
method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.filled.html#numpy-ma-maskedarray-filled). `marr.filled(np.nan)` is equivalent to `np.ma.filled(marr, np.nan)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the mask by the data so that all masked elements will equal zero, eg:

```
a=np.random.rand(500,500)
b=ma.masked_greater(a, .5)
result=b.data*b.mask
```

This can then be converted to nan using

```
result[result==0] = np.nan
```